# What does Usain Bolt's Bolt ability do?

Tags: temple-run-2

A Temple Run 2 update was just released, which added Usain Bolt and his mysterious Bolt Power ability to the game. This is a thing that happened.

[image: Limited Time - Purchase - Usain Bolt]
[image: Bolt - Engages Bolt Power instantly - Buy Usain Bolt to unlock]

Irritatingly enough, he's not available for coins at all. Unlocking him is a straight-up in-app purchase ($0.99/regional equivalent), probably for licensing reasons.

So before considering a purchase, I'd like to know: What does his unique ability do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It [combines](http://www.joystiq.com/2013/08/01/temple-run-2-adds-usain-bolt-because-it-can-and-why-not/) speed boost with coin magnet:

> Of course, being Usain Bolt, he has a unique power-up that combines
>   the speed boost with the coin magnet; we're not sure there's a better
>   analogy for his lucrative life.